# How to get most popular media by user name or by some custom parameter?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

How to get most popular media by user name or by some custom parameter?
I used below instagram API
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?client_id=CLIENT_ID

But in https://apigee.com API console we can specify some custom parameter in API console but i am not getting how to use those custom parameter?

Thanks for your kind help.

Sanjeev Dutta